# Meaning of 'across' in 'across a surface'

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, word-meaning

I came across the following sentence in an article:

> Radiation is generated as the electrons move across the surface of the metallic sample.

Which direction of movement is considered here?

1. The electrons move from the inside of the sample to outside, crossing the surface of the sample.
2. The electrons remain on the surface, just their position on the surface is changed.

I'm a physicist. Both are physically possible. I'd like to know which is intended by the author.

Update:

The article can be found at https://doi.org/10.1017/hpl.2018.21

The original sentence:

> It is thought that these electrons contribute towards the EMP in three key stages, starting with the emission of THz radiation as they propagate across the target surface.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147910/discussion-on-question-by-apadana-meaning-of-across-in-across-a-surface); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.